# What does `Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores` for standard edition mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, license

What does `Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores` for standard edition mean?

Since a socket has cores, I think of it like apples - for example: lesser of 4 apples or 24 slices.

Is it assuming that each socket can have max 8 cores? or this is not important?

1. If I have 4 sockets (each with 8 cores) then does SQL only use 4 sockets and 6 cores in each (effectively 24 cores)?
2. If I have 6 sockets (each with 4 cores) - then it will consider only 4 sockets (effectively I have 4*4=16 cores)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read these two reference. It has details about your question.

- [Nodes Offline: Why Your SQL Server VM Can’t Use All Its Virtual Hardware](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/06/cpu-cores-or-memory-offline-the-problem-with-standard-edition-vms/) by Brent Ozar
- [SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition Licensing](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-2019-standard-edition-licensing/) by Glenn Berry

**Since a socket has cores, I think of it like apples - for example: lesser of 4 apples or 24 slices.**

Yes, but each apple also can be regarded as one slice.

**Is it assuming that each socket can have max 8 cores?**

No, it is not. It is entirely up to you how you configure, especially virtual machines.

**or this is not important?**
It is very important. If you configure 1 core per socket and 1 logical processor per socket, you will use only 4 logical processors.

**If I have 4 sockets (each with 8 cores) then does SQL only use 4 sockets and 6 cores in each (effectively 24 cores)?**

I am unsure if it will use 4 sockets and 6 cores or 3 with all cores.

**If I have 6 sockets (each with 4 cores) - then it will consider only 4 sockets (effectively I have 4*4=16 cores)?**

Yes

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's referring to the compute capacity.
So it's actually referring to a limitation for the community edition:

IF you have 4 sockets open, or IF 24 cores available you have reached the limit.
For example:

I use 4 sockets, but only 10 cores => Limitation reached.

OR

I use 2 sockets, but 24 cores => Limitation reached.

It's the point where to increase in computational capacity is halted for the community edition. I hope that makes sense.
It's done to allow usage for development and small businesses, but MS still wants to make money on big corporations.

Comment: The question is about [compute capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/compute-capacity-limits-by-edition-of-sql-server) for SQL Server Standard Edition. There is no community edition of SQL Server. FYI, the free Developer edition has the same compute as Enterprise Edition but licensed only for dev and testing use. MS doesn't make money on that.